# Hive error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, sockets, hive, centos, centos7

I installed MySQL Server in CentOS 7:

```
[root@master1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
mysql-community-server-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64
```

Now I need to execute the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p welcome123 
CREATE USER 'hive'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepwd';
```

However, I get the following error:

```
[root@master1 ~]# mysql -u root -p welcome123
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I read the recommendations that it's necessary to check `my.cnf` but I cannot find this file:

```
[root@master1 ~]# vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
[root@master1 ~]# cd /etc/mysql/
-bash: cd: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
```

Finally, I tried to reset the password:

```
[root@master1 ~]# mysqladmin password newpassword
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

I also tried `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`. It asks me to enter a root password. So, I generated the password, but it's not accepted and provides the above-shown error.

```
grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log |tail -1
```

P.S.

I think that MySQL Server is not actually running:

```
[root@master1 ~]# ps -ef | grep mysql
root     17964     1  0 17:12 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
root     20359 14673  0 17:17 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
root     21799 14673  0 17:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Then I re-install it just in case:

```
[root@master1 ~]# yum install -y mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.uv.es
 * extras: mirror.uv.es
 * updates: mirror.uv.es
Package mysql-community-server-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

When I want to start the service, it lasts forever:

```
[root@master1 ~]# systemctl start mysqld.service
```